# Where exactly does the "description" method get overriden?

Tags: objective-c, nsobject, foundation

The `description` method is a class method of the `NSObject` class. I guess it's a class method, because `NSObject` cannot be initialized.

When I do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSObject description]);
```

It prints out:

```
NSObject
```

But when I create a class that directly inherits from `NSObject`, and do this:

```
MyNewClass *obj = [[MyNewClass alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", obj);
```

This prints out something like:

```
<MyNewClass: 0x4b234a0>
```

I didn't specifically override the `description` method, how did it get overriden by my new class?

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"%@", [MyNewClass description]);` to make the comparison apples-to-apples :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `NSLog` automatically calls the description method, but you're right, it might be confusing.

Comment: It does, but it's a different one.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, sorry I get what you mean now. My second day on Mac development, everything looks confusing right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `NSObject` has two methods:

```
+ (NSString *)description; // Class method 
- (NSString *)description; // Instance method
```

Former is defined in [NSObject class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/description) and later one in in [NSObject Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description).

Comment: I was checking "NSObject Class Reference" on Mac Developer Library, and "- description" was not included there, that's what confused me. Apparently it's in "NSObject Protocol Reference."

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Glad I could help clarifying!